# HTML select with insertion option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-plugins, unobtrusive-javascript

I need to render a `<select>` with some values.

Those values correspond to a model that the rendered view's model `belongs_to` - e.g. Foo `has_many` Bar, I'm rendering Bar, and its form should include Foo's ids and names in the `<select>`.

That is no problem - right now I'm using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) for that.

But in addition to a fixed set of values, the user should be able to insert a new Foo aynchronously (in some popup / whatever), updating the `<select>` in the browser with the newly-generated id, and the given name.

That is no problem to implement by hand, but is there a Rails feature (like UJS) or plugin (like simple_form) which provides exactly that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [selectize-rails](https://github.com/manuelvanrijn/selectize-rails)

Examples can be found here. http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/